# Alpine: Incomplete maildomain

Tags: centos-7, alpine-mail

How do I set the maildomain for Alpine? 
(I'm on CentOS 7.) 
It gives me this error and beeps at me twice when starting.

```
[Incomplete maildomain "fsphub".]

[Return address in mail you send may be incorrect.]
```

`hostname` returns the full domain. I found this page

http://www.washington.edu/alpine/tech-notes/config.html

But it's so dense it's completely useless to search for 'domain' or 'maildomain'

> *quell-maildomain-warning*
>
>   When your configuration is set up so that your domain name contains no dots, it is usually a configuration error. 
>     By default,
>   *Alpine*
>   will warn you about this when you start it up. 
>     You will see a warning message that looks like
>
> ```
> Incomplete maildomain "<domain>".
> ```
>
> If this feature is set, the warning is turned off. 
>   This feature is displayed as "Suppress Maildomain Warning".

That doesn't tell you how to fix it! The top makes reference to `/usr/local/lib/pine.conf` but that file doesn't exist.

Comment: For now, I found and edited `nano ~/.pinerc` and added the domain to `user-domain=`.

Answer (score 0):

In ~/.pinerc look for feature-list= and make it

```
    feature-list=quell-maildomain-warning
```

You can also use the config editor in alpine, where it is listed as "Suppress Maildomain Warning".

That's assuming you want to use a user-domain that alpine thinks is incomplete.  (E.g. for peer-to-peer email).  If you were asking how to set it in alpine, select 'Setup' / 'Config' and it is the 2nd config item.